# Outlook for two users not working after Mailbox was moved from 2010 to 2013 database

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2013

There have been over 100 moves but only these two users, from last night, are reporting issues. On the network Outlook connects fine but off of our network Outlook Anywhere appears to not be working. Outlook says disconnected and we can't get it to connect again.

I've had them reboot their machine and outlook, switch to ntlm and negotiated authentication, verified that OWA and Outlook from the LAN work. I'm not sure where to look next. Both move requests appear to have completed successfully.

Update: If I create a new profile on a laptop while on the domain and connect to Outlook their profile connects as expected. If I then join it to an external network Outlook Anywhere works properly.

I believe the issue is tied to them not being in the office after the mailbox move completed to the new systems and suspect when they get back to the office and connect internally things will resolve.

I would like to find a way to solve this for them remotely however.

Comment: Have you performed these restarts yourself and/or change the user's passwords, and log into their profiles yourself on a test system?

Comment: Yes, I have a laptop which I just logged in to with their account information then I connected to an external network and am trying to set up Outlook now. It did not work with the default conifg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I logged in as them on a machine locally and on the domain their mailbox would load properly. After waiting 5-10 minutes it would propagate to their remote system and load for them without them having to come in to the office.